# Is this a good way to format a fairly complicated sentence including a list and a quote/dialogue?

Tags: punctuation

I am trying to improve my grammar (British or UK English) and struggling with the following:

> It didn’t matter what the job was: paint a fence, load a lorry or dig a hole - the price he would quote was always the same, ‘Give us a quid’.

The above seems ok, but I wonder if it is correct.

My considerations are:

1. It's kind of a list so a colon seems appropriate
2. The second independent clause needs to be 'linked' but to use a semicolon would complicate things because I have already used a colon, a comma may seem confusing, so I have used an em dash.
3. Would it be better as two separate sentences, as in:

> It didn’t matter what the job was: paint a fence, load a lorry or dig a hole. The price he would quote was always the same, ‘Give us a quid’.

This last option seems correct but destroys the flow.

Lastly, should it be at the end - ‘Give us a quid’ ? I ask because usually the period would be inside the quotes - ‘Give us a quid.' but it is at the end of a sentence.

Comment: I'd opt for 'It didn’t matter what the job was – paint a fence, load a lorry or dig a hole – the price he would quote was always the same. "Give us a quid." ' Colons are dated in this sort of usage, and balanced dashes around the parenthetical (which I'd label an appositive) are less fussy. I'm happy with the conversational separation of quotative structure ('the price he would quote was always the same') and quote into different sentences.

Comment: Or *It didn’t matter what the job was—paint a fence, load a lorry or dig a hole—the price he would quote was always the same: ‘Give us a quid.’*

Comment: You probably want to ask this on [ell.se]

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth - That sounds good, thanks, my only concern would be that the end of the thought 'Give us a quid' is now kind of disconnected ie. a separate sentence. If you simply took that on its own it is not a complete independent clause. What do you think, am I over thinking it

Comment: @DjinTonic - thanks for the feedback, but is it not bad practice to have to em dashes in the same sentence?

Comment: @Mitch - Thanks for the suggestion but I think that forum is for foreign language speakers learning English - is my English that bad? :-)

Comment: It _is_ an imperative independent clause, but 'quid' certainly licenses the abruptness.

Comment: @kerry Oh, no your grammar is fine, it's just that anything that asks for 'is this correct?' is probably more appropriate for that site. ELU isn't about writing advice or correcting grammar, which are more for [writers.se] and [ell.se].

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth - that's a good point that I hadn't considered

Comment: I don't know enough to really answer but I do know that in American punctuation rules, the period of the sentence goes inside the quotes, even if it is not part of the quoted sentence (which has the difficulty of being possibly inconsistent with what is intended). I've hear that in the UK, the style is to keep the quote verbatim (if it is a question then keep the question mark), and then punctuate the sentence as normal (if it is a statement then a period).

Comment: No, it can't be an appositive, as substitution doesn't work. A deleted ('It might be' / 'Whether it was' ...) expansion on 'the job'.

Comment: Btw, ELL has the same requirement as here: open-ended proofing requests are off topic; questions must focus on a specific concern. The key point here is that the list is an “aside.” You have a number of punctuation options for setting it off— commas, parentheses, em dashes—but they should be matched pairs (as I just did with dashes). Personally, I would go with the dashes; the commas would read awkwardly, and parentheses imply a, well, parenthetical nature that isn’t intended. Also, I feel like the spot that’s begging for a colon is the join between the main sentence and the quote!

Comment: Also, note that your list does not use the “Oxford comma.“ That’s easily the most divisive and charged grammar topic of our time, so I in no way take a position about that, but make sure you choose yours knowingly and intentionally.

Comment: @kerry On the contrary, a pair of [em dashes](https://editorsmanual.com/articles/em-dash/) is used to set off parenthetical material.

Comment: OK, so based on consensus, it seems the best option may be as DjinTonic suggested, with the Oxford comma as suggested by Andy Bonner ie. It didn’t matter what the job was—paint a fence, load a lorry, or dig a hole—the price he would quote was always the same: ‘Give us a quid.’

Comment: @DjinTonic - just an aside, but how did you manage to include italics in your comment?

Comment: You have to tip the moderators monthly for this privilege. Seriously, just place a * immediately before and after your text.

Comment: @Djin Tonic - thanks, *5 quid on the way!*